# angular: how to make a button disabled based on a condition

Tags: angularjs

Sorry for not being specific, but I'm having a blackout and am desperate.
Have been struggling for 2 days now to find the logic to do the following:
every item has a 'inCart' value. if it's 0, it's not in there, if it's below 7, it's in one of 6 'slots' depending on the value.

now i have buttons that assign each item to a value in inCart.
but if one of the items has a value in it that is 4, then I obviously don't want all the items to show a button that will assign it to 4.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myItems">
<a ng-repeat="slot in [1,2,3,4,5,6]" ng-click="addToCart(x._id, slot)"
   class="btn btn-primary {{x.inCart != '0' ? 'disabled' : ''}}">
    {{slot}}
</a></tr>
```

Thinking about it logically I know my mistake: i only look if the current item is in the cart, and if it is then it disables the button. How do I look at all the items in the cart, and if one of them is for example 4, then all the buttons that assign an a value 4 to inCart are disabled, so that I won't have multiple items with the same location inCart.

based on the approach I can fix this I am pretty sure I can make everything work better then how it is now, it's just that I can't even figure this out so let alone the more detailed issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

You can evaluate a `expression` with ng-class and if it's `true` you can apply a certain class. If not, then the class won’t be applied.

```
<button ng-class="{'disabled': expression}">
```

Comment: what should the expression be to evaluate inCart values in all my items?

Comment: This doesn't disable the button. It just adds a class for you to add that logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an actual button, you can make use of [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

```
<input type="button" ng-repeat="slot in [1,2,3,4,5,6]" 
       ng-click="addToCart(x._id, slot)"
       class="btn btn-primary"
       ng-disabled="x.inCart !== '0'" value="{{slot}}" />
```

Comment: the problem is that for my next row of buttons, all buttons are enabled, because that row of buttons is based on a new item in x, where it has not yet have a value in inCart. however, if one of the items in x has a number, lets say 4, I want the button that will assign 4 to it, to be disabled

Comment: Can you not process the slots first before doing `ng-repeat`?  That way you have the data available upfront and you can use `ng-disabled` as described here.

Comment: process it first before ng-repeat?
I don't think I understand, I'm ng-repeating my items, and then for each item i show buttons. my brain is really messed up now, have been staring at this problem too long i think

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function to check if the slot is available.

**Controller**

```
// return the slots already used
var slotsUsed = $scope.myItems.map(function (i) {return i.inCart;}).filter( function(s) { return s > 0;});

$scope.slotAvailable = function(s) { 
    return slotsUsed.indexOf(s) == -1;
}
```

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myItems">
    <td>  
        <a ng-repeat="slot in [1,2,3,4,5,6]" 
            class="btn btn-primary"
            ng-click="addToCart(x._id, slot)"
            ng-class="{'disabled': x.inCart != '0' || !slotAvailable(slot)}">
            {{slot}}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried googling information about .map but I can't find something to read on. based on your comment I can make some sense out of it. I can then create buttons using `ng-if="slotsAvailble[slots] == slots"` ?

Comment: I think that `map` is an `underscore.js` function which can be downloaded at [http://underscorejs.org/](http://underscorejs.org/).

Comment: It's only javascript: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

There's a directive designed specifically for this: `ngDisabled`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled